# How to setup Azure VPN P2S with outbound Internet access with a static IP?

Tags: vpn, azure, azure-networking, azure-vpn

I want to setup an Azure VNET with an Azure VPN Gateway.  Then when I VPN into the gateway, I want to have outbound Internet access for P2S VPN from clients.  I want this outbound Internet access to have a static IP.

This seems like a pretty simple thing to do, but very hard to figure out how to do it in practice.  I opened a support ticket with Azure and they were no help at all.

Here is what I have tried so far:

- Created an Azure VNET with 1 subnet
- Created an Azure VPN Gateway in the same region and connected it to the VNET (bringing total subnets to 2)
  --- Note that this VPN Gateway has its own subnet (which seems to be required) in the VNET
- Configured P2S connection with Azure AD auth on the VPN Gateway; configured this P2S to advertise all routes
- Installed Azure VPN Client software and imported configuration
- Configured an Azure Firewall on the VNET
- Setup a route table in the VNET from the core Subnet (not the VPN Gateway Subnet, which does not allow this) to the Azure Firewall
- Configured outbound Internet access for all source IPs to all destination IPs on all ports and protocols on the Azure Firewall

OK - so seems like then if I then VPN I should be able to access the Internet right?  Unfortunately no, when I VPN I do get an IP, and I can ping the firewall private IP, but I cannot go to any websites, e.g. google.com.

Does anyone know where I am going wrong here?  Any ideas would be greatly appreciated

Comment: were you able to resolve this? I have the exact same set up as you have done and the use case is also same. It would be great if you can share your findings if you ever got this working?

Answer (score 0):

When you connect to the VPN, what does your route table look like? It seems like you have no outlet to the Internet when connected - you probably do not have a default route - 0.0.0.0/0 to advertise to your own VPN clients.

You are able to ping the firewall because you only see the internal Azure resources or directly connected subnets.

Please, give one route print and have a look where your default gateway is.

Answer (score 0):

Internet breakout is not supported at the moment.
See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/nat-overview